# Build chaincode(hyperledger) on Atom on Windows fail

Tags: go, atom-editor, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to build simple chaincode example in Atom editor on Windows but build fails (I'm using go-plus package) with following error:

```
fatal error: ltdl.h: No such file or directory #include ltdl.h
```

I know that using flag: `-tags nopkcs11` will solve the problem, but how can i configure go-plus/Atom to use this flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is still an [open issue for go-plus](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/573) to support build tags.  I have not used Atom in a while, but the only option I can think of would be to try to use a Makefile (which is not the easiest thing in the world on Windows since most of the built-in Atom commands assume GNU commands being available).

If you are open to moving to something like Visual Studio Code it does support build tags.

Perhaps we should actually reverse the build tag within Fabric and require you to enabled pkcs11 with a tag rather than disable it with a tag.  I debated this when first adding the tag.  Feel free to open up a [JIRA item](https://jira.hyperledger.org) for this.

Comment: I moved to Visual Studio Code and everything works fine. I didn't even need to specify the build tags, no build errors, autocompletion works fine. Does it mean that Visual Studio doesn't rebuild all dependencies (like Atom does)? Btw, i already built fabric code with -nopkcs11 outside any dev environment.